# Repeating the same action when composition actions in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, annotations, playframework-2.5

I'm using Play Framework to develop a server. In several of my methods I need to perform some previous action (basically input checking) so I think the best way of doing this is [Action Composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition).

I can use several annotations without problem

```
@Action1 // <---------------------------------------- This action is executed
@Action2(value = "someValue") // <------------------- This action is executed
public CompletionStage<Result> doSomething() {
    ...
}
```

but as soon as I try to repeat one of these actions that concrete action doesn't execute:

```
@Action1 // <---------------------------------------- This action is executed
@Action2(value = "someValue") // <------------------- This action is not executed
@Action2(value = "someOtherValue") // <-------------- This action is not executed
public CompletionStage<Result> doSomething() {
    ...
}
```

My `Action1` annotation looks like the `VerboseAnnotation` of the [Play Framework example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition#defining-custom-action-annotations) so I don't think it's worthy to write it here. As my `Action2` annotation can be repeated I've declared a `RepeatableAction2` annotation like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RepeatableAction2 {
    Action2[] value() default {};
}
```

and `Action2` looks like this:

```
@With(Action2Impl.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(value = RepeatableAction2.class)
public @interface Action2 {
    String value();
}
```

The method is correctly annotated. When I add:

```
for (Method m : Application.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    RequiredJsonValues reqs = m.getAnnotation(RequiredJsonValues.class);
    for (RequiredJsonValue req : reqs.value()) {
        System.out.println("Method: " + m + " annotation: " + req);
    }
}
```

at the beginning of the method I get

```
Method: public java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage controllers.SomeController.doSomething() annotation: @util.Action2(value=someValue)
Method: public java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage controllers.SomeController.doSomething() annotation: @util.Action2(value=someOtherValue)
```

So what am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to chain the same action several times with different values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it work

As Explained [in here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/03/java-8-repeating-annotation-explained-in-5-minutes/) the Java 8 compiler does not need the `RepeatableAction2` to be written but it adds it at compile time so I needed to add an implementation for that annotation:

```
@With(RepeatableAction2Impl.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RepeatableAction2 {
    Action2[] value() default {};
}
```

and in the implementation I manually chain all the actions:

```
public class RepeatableAction2Impl extends Action<RepeatableAction2> {

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) {
        if (configuration.value().length > 0) {
            int actions = configuration.value().length;
            List<Action<Action2>> actionList = new ArrayList<>();
            // Create actions
            for (int i = 0; i < actions; i++) {
                Action2Impl action2Impl = new Action2Impl();
                action2Impl.configuration = configuration.value()[i];
                actionList.add(action2Impl);
            }
            // Chaining
            actionList.get(actions - 1).delegate = delegate;
            for (int i = 0; i < actions - 1; i++) {
                actionList.get(i).delegate = actionList.get(i + 1);
            }
            // Delegate the work to actions
            return actionList.get(0).call(ctx);
        } else {
            return delegate.call(ctx);
        }
    }

}
```

Although it's a working solution it's still seems a bit ugly to me. Is there any other way I'm missing?